# Use my existing jquery function in drupal 7

Tags: 7, javascript

I have my function like this in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // set the map-wrapper width and height to match the img size
    $('#map-wrapper').css({'width':$('#map-wrapper img').width(),
                      'height':$('#map-wrapper img').height()
    })

    for (i=0; i<$(".pin").length; i++)
    {
        // store initial tooltips contents within an array
        var tooltipContent = new Array();
        tooltipContent[i] = $(".pin").eq(i).html();

        // set tooltip direction type - up or down
        var tooltipDirection = 'tooltip-up';             
        if ($(".pin").eq(i).hasClass('pin-down'))
        {
            tooltipDirection = 'tooltip-down';
        }

        // append the tooltip
        $("#map-wrapper").append("<div style='left:"+$(".pin").eq(i).data('xpos')+"px;top:"+$(".pin").eq(i).data('ypos')+"px' class='" + tooltipDirection +"'>\
                                            <div class='tooltip'>" + tooltipContent[i] + "</div>\
                                    </div>");
    }    

    // show/hide the tooltip
    $('.tooltip-up, .tooltip-down').mouseenter(function(){
                $(this).children('.tooltip').fadeIn(100);
            }).mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).children('.tooltip').fadeOut(100);
            })
});
```

But i am unable to use it in Drupal 7 . So what changes do i need to make for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your are missign two important things. First, in [Drupal 7 jQuery is namespaced](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#javascript_compatibility) to [avoid conflict with other JavaScript libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries). So you should either wrap your code in an anonymous function to assign the `jQuery` object to the `$` variable (ie. `(function($){...})(jQuery);`) or use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Second, you shouldn't use `$(document).ready()` but add you code as a the attach function under the `Drupal.behaviors.yourModule` namespace. Behaviors are attached on the `document`object on load, but also to any new element added to the page by any well behaving scripts (the ones that call `Drupal.attachBehaviors()`). Finally, because behaviors could be attached several times to the same DOM tree, you should avoid processing the same element multiple times. This can easily be done with jQuery Once.

```
(function($){
  Drupal.behaviors.myFunkyModule = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      // Get the map wrapper element (anywhere in the document).
      var map_wrapper = $('#map-wrapper');
      //Set the map-wrapper width and height to match the img size only once.
      map_wrapper.once('my-funky-module').css({
        width: $('#map-wrapper img').width(),
        height: $('#map-wrapper img').height()
      })
      // Get the (un-processed) .pin elements, in the context (ie. DOM tree) our behavior is attached to.
      var pins = $(".pin", context).once('my-funky-module');
      // Process the pin elements (note: this could also be done using jQuery.each()).
      for (i=0; i<pins.length; i++) {
           var pin = pins.eq(i);
          // store initial tooltips contents within an array
          var tooltipContent = new Array();
          tooltipContent[i] = pin.html();

          // set tooltip direction type - up or down
          var tooltipDirection = 'tooltip-up';             
          if (pin.hasClass('pin-down')) {
              tooltipDirection = 'tooltip-down';
          }

          // Append the tooltip elements to the #map_wrapper one.
          map_wrapper.append("<div style='left:"+pin.data('xpos')+"px;top:"+pin.data('ypos')+"px' class='" + tooltipDirection +"'><div class='tooltip'>" + tooltipContent[i] + "</div></div>");
      }    

      // Add event listeners to show/hide the tooltip, again this only need to be done once.
      $('.tooltip-up, .tooltip-down').once('my-funky-module').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).children('.tooltip').fadeIn(100);
      }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children('.tooltip').fadeOut(100);
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: what about if your jquery needs to run at a time other than when the DOM is ready, i.e. when all the images have loaded, what would be the convention then? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102392/behaviors-jquery-whats-the-standard-convention-in-drupal-7-for-running-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the entire function into this:

```
(function($) {

  //.. your function here ..



}(jQuery));
```

then you would get:

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function(){

      // set the map-wrapper width and height to match the img size
      $('#map-wrapper').css({'width':$('#map-wrapper img').width(),
                        'height':$('#map-wrapper img').height()
      })

      for (i=0; i<$(".pin").length; i++)
      {
          // store initial tooltips contents within an array
          var tooltipContent = new Array();
          tooltipContent[i] = $(".pin").eq(i).html();

          // set tooltip direction type - up or down
          var tooltipDirection = 'tooltip-up';             
          if ($(".pin").eq(i).hasClass('pin-down'))
          {
              tooltipDirection = 'tooltip-down';
          }

          // append the tooltip
          $("#map-wrapper").append("<div style='left:"+$(".pin").eq(i).data('xpos')+"px;top:"+$(".pin").eq(i).data('ypos')+"px' class='" + tooltipDirection +"'>\
                                              <div class='tooltip'>" + tooltipContent[i] + "</div>\
                                      </div>");
      }    

      // show/hide the tooltip
      $('.tooltip-up, .tooltip-down').mouseenter(function(){
                  $(this).children('.tooltip').fadeIn(100);
              }).mouseleave(function(){
                  $(this).children('.tooltip').fadeOut(100);
              })
  });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: While this will make it work, you should additionaly use Drupal behaviors instead of document.ready.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(function($){

  // your code

})(jQuery);
```

Have you added the file with the drupal_add_js() function or have you added it to your template.info file?