# Adding jQuery Timeline to Drupal

Tags: 7, javascript

I have found this awesome [jQuery Timelinr](http://www.csslab.cl/ejemplos/timelinr/latest/vertical.html) that I have customized for my Drupal site but am now at a loss at how to insert it. It is only going to be on one page. Does it need to be in a block? Do I have to make a custom module? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. Easy one is to add it on your theme's .info file: `scripts[] = js/your_jquery_plugin.js`
But then its everywhere.

You can add it in a block. Check that your text-filter is set to PHP (May need to be active in the modules: PHP filter). Then add [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I went ahead and used the drupal_add_js() in a page as suggested above. I am still having trouble with the formatting of the function. How do I drupalize it? 

$(function(){
   $().timelinr({
    orientation: 'vertical',
    issuesSpeed: 300,
    datesSpeed: 100,
    issuesSpeed: 500,
    arrowKeys: 'true',
    startAt: 3
   })
  });

Comment: your $().timelinr(){}; lacks where it should be applied. $("#IDsomething").timelinr(){}

ps: you can upvote the answers you like. Arrow up.

Comment: Sorry I have been MIA. It's finals week. That bit of code above works without anything on a regular page, just not in drupal. I tried putting the timeline div name (as that is where it should be applied) but that still does not work. The jquery is loading and I put all the necessary markup in the body but it is still a no go. Anything else you could suggest?

Answer (score 1):

If it's only o one page you can also create a plane new page set the text filter to PHP and add the [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) code.

See [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16491/use-my-existing-jquery-function-in-drupal-7) for some hints about integrating custom jQuery code into Drupal.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used your suggestion but am still having trouble formatting the function (see below). Let me know if you have any ideas on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you resolve it meanwhile? If not, I suppose it is because of jquery-version conflicts. The Drupal built-in version is NOT new enough for this script; even the jQuery Update module does not bring the newest version. I had the same problem when trying to implement another jQuery script. I resolved it by removing the built-in jQuery and adding the new one. I did that in the page template. I know, it is not recommended.